# A groupby and aggregation function is giving an unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, operators, aggregate, python-itertools

Dear Stack Overflow Community,

I have built a customized groupby function in order to groupby keys in a dictionary and aggregate them by summation. The function is written as below,

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def group_by_field(data, fields):
    groups = []
    agg_group = itemgetter(*[item for item in fields])
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key = agg_group)
    for key, group in groupby(sorted_data, agg_group):
        dictionary = dict(zip([item for item in fields], key))
        dictionary["items"] = sum(item["items"] for item in group)
        groups.append(dictionary)
    return groups
```

My data is a dictionary or a json file and it is read as below,

```
with gzip.open('data.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

And the second argument of my function is a tuple of variables presented in this way,

```
('bnf_name',)
```

or

```
('bnf_name', 'post_code',)
```

The function is working well in both cases, but when I provide only one variable it reduces the name of the variable. please look at the attached image to see the results of both cases. [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXtS4.png)

I would like to know why the function is behaving in this way, and wait for any suggestion that would solve my problem.